# Using xsl string for xml file Transformation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, string, xslt

I need to construct an xslt string from input that the user will provide in a textarea element. I will, of course, retrieve the input in a Javascript function. Then, I need to use that string to transform a pre existing xml file, and display the results in an html table.
This is a snippet of my code...which, of course, doesn't work.

```
   var msg=document.getElementById("query_txt").value;

if (window.DOMParser)
{
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(msg,"text/xml");
}
else 
{
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML("datastore.xml");
    var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xsl.async = false ;
    xsl.load(msg);
    // Transform 
    document.write(xmlDoc.transformNode(xsl));
}
```

The XML document is as follows....jus one entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?-->


<catalog xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/schema.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com schema.xsd">


<university name="Very Great University">
<name>Great University</name>
<city>Lahore</city>
<reg_num>124</reg_num>
</university>


</catalog>
```

I don't knw what exactly should be part of the xsl string. I'm assuming it must be similar to an xsl file...this would have been the xsl file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:nsm="http://www.w3schools.com/schema.xsd"


>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="nsm:catalog/nsm:university">

    <xsl:value-of select="nsm:name" />
      <xsl:value-of select="nsm:city" />


    </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looks like your `document.write(xmlDoc.transformNode(xsl));` is stuck inside an else block that might not ever trigger (if you're testing it on a non-MSIE browser).  Other than that, if you can provide a minimally complete example (i.e. an XSL string and XML it's supposed to transform), that'd be helpful.

Comment: I've just added them. So u'r saying it should work, as it is, on Internet Explorer (since that would trigger the else option)? Please let me knw a cross browser solution as well

Comment: You're still missing some of the JavaScript code.  I'm saying if it were to work at all, i tcould only possible work on Internet Explorer based on what you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing XSLT or XML, it is (very) tricky to get it cross-browser compatible and it is easy to introduce errors (as Dan Field has pointed out in the comments). Have a look at the [Sarissa JS library](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/), which resolves these issues. I have used it years ago and found that tasks like the one in your question become trivial and can be coded understandably. Also, the Sarissa site has a number of examples you may be able to use.

Here's [How to load a DOM Document from an XML string](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html#loadstring), which is what you seem to be trying to achieve here (and is the step required prior to using the XSLT).

And this example shows you how to use an XSLT string as input document for a transformation: [How to transform a DOM Document Object with XSLT](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html#transform).